# Cocoapods cannot install pod

Tags: macos, cocoapods, podfile

I ran `pod install` after I updated my `Podfile`, the `LeanCloud` pod was not installed, and I got the following message:

> Analyzing dependencies
>   [!] There are only pre-release versions available satisfying the following requirements:
>
> 'LeanCloud', '>= 0'
>
> You should explicitly specify the version in order to install a pre-release version

Here is how my `Podfile` looks like:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'todolist' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for todolist
 pod 'Alamofire'
 pod 'SwiftyJSON'
 pod 'LeanCloud', '>= 0'
end
```

I'm running on macOS 10.12.3, with Cocoapods Version 1.2.0

Comment: I tried your podfile and it work properly

Comment: That's very strange. I tried to reinstall `Cocoapods`, update pod repo. nothing would work.

Comment: @f_qi have you tried to delete the .xcworspace file, pods and do pod install/update?

Comment: I see [version 10.0.0](https://cocoapods.org/?q=on%3Aios%20LeanCloud) is available. So you should use `pod` `'LeanCloud',` `'~>10.0.0'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Somehow I got it to work by move the line `pod LeanCloud` to be the first pod, and ran `pod update`.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'todolist' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for todolist
 pod 'LeanCloud'
 pod 'Alamofire'
 pod 'SwiftyJSON' 
end
```

> ⇒  pod update
>   Update all pods
>   Updating local specs repositories
>
> CocoaPods 1.2.1.beta.1 is available.
>   To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
>   [!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.
>
> For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.2.1.beta.1
>
> Analyzing dependencies
>   Downloading dependencies
>   Installing Alamofire 4.2.0 (was 4.4.0)
>   Installing LeanCloud (10.0.0)
>   Using SwiftyJSON (3.1.4)
>   Generating Pods project
>   Integrating client project
>   Sending stats
>   Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 3 total pods installed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the order of the pods you specify. It's currently working because you haven't specify the **version** of the pod. So the most recent version will be used.

Comment: Initially I tried with no version specify, but it gave me the same message, as me to specify a version, then I tried your #2. Same message. That's why I post this question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify which version of a dependency you’d like to use. Take a look here how versioning works:

1. == 1.0 means “Use exactly version 1.0”
2. >= 1.0 means “Use version 1.0 or higher”
3. ~> 1.0 means “Use any version that’s compatible with 1.0″, essentially meaning any version up until the next major release. That is:

   - If you specify ~> 1.7.5, then any version from 1.7.5 up to, but not including 2.0, is considered compatible.
   - Likewise, if you specify ~> 2.0 then `Cocoapods` will use a version 2.0 or later, but less than 3.0.
   - Compatibility is based on [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org)

From [here](https://cocoapods.org/?q=LeanCloud), you have to choose which `LeanCloud` version you want to use. Then change it accordingly in your pod file based on those steps above.

Comment: You tried with `pod 'LeanCloud', '>= 0'`, right? Now can you try with `pod 'LeanCloud', '>= 10.0'`??

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good in English
I think you did not specify a mobile version

## platform :ios, '9.0'  <-You should try to open this sentence

Comment: pod 'LeanCloud', '>= 0'  change  pod 'LeanCloud', '~> 0'